# Keyboard input using ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, input

I am learning how to use Flash using CS4, and focusing mainly on ActionScript3 (since I come from a coding background and not a designer background).

I want to respond to the user pressing keys on the keyboard.

I have used the official example source at the [Flash reference site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary) and followed the  [CS4 instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/ExampleInstruct.html) for classes.
However, all it responds to is special keys like ctrl and shift, for these keys it works fine. For keys like a,b,c there is no response whatsoever. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some setting I need to change? Maybe I need to change something outside my ActionScript (like a project setting maybe).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is tremendously late, but have you tried stage.AddEventListerner( KeyboardEvent.KEYDOWN, myListener )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quite usual problem is that the Flash IDE shortcut keys won't respond (as they are used by the IDE). Make sure you also test your movie in a browser or in the standalone player.

Comment: I'm using trace() for my output, how can I see this output using the standalone player?

Comment: I don't think you can, two options would be to setup a text field and change it's value, or look into using Flash Develop or another IDE.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of to trace in the browser is to call a Javascript function from Flash that will do a Console.log in firefox with firebug installed.

Comment: Yes, that did it :-)
I tested it in the standalone player and it works there.. Thanks for that.
Do you happen to know if there's a way to not send keyboard output to the IDE? I'm currently using a Label to view my output.. but it's a lot more convenient if I can use my movie fully inside my IDE, using trace() and ctrl+enter to run it..

Comment: Oops, found this myself. For those wondering the same thing:
When you run "Test Movie" (ctrl+enter), a new window will pop up running the Movie.
In this window, go to the Control menu and check the option: Disable Keyboard Shortcuts.
This will stop forwarding the keys, and it will also remember it for future startups of this file.

This means I can still test my movies as normal :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running it in full screen mode? You can't hear those keys if you are. (Security restriction)

Comment: No, just doing the regular ctrl+enter in CS4 (Test movie)

Comment: The code is in the link I mentioned in my question. I encountered it in my own code, but when testing with this official example I had the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

The up and down handlers trap different kinds of keys:

**KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN** gets keyslike backspace and delete, while
**KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP** gets the usual a-z suspects.